# How to add space in between bracket in vs code for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to format my c++ code like this:

```
void foo( T bar );
```

But every time I format the code, it will delete the spaces to

```
void foo(T bar);
```

I know in vs code typescript and javascript can enable

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true,
```

But how can I enable it in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the Microsoft C/C++ extension installed, it uses clang-format to format code.  Take a look at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html for a list of options and how to configure it.  **SpacesInParentheses** looks like the setting you are interested in. You can either create a `.clang-format` file in your workspace folder with that setting in it, or add a raw configuration to the `C_Cpp.clang_format_style` setting.